# Error "'what' must be a character string or a function" using lme4::glmer in R

Tags: r

I got the following error message even using the example from lme4::glmer:

```
>require(lme4)
> (gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
+               data = cbpp, family = binomial))
Error in do.call(new, c(list(Class = "glmResp", family = family), ll[setdiff(names(ll),  : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function
```

I hunted around and can't figure out what's wrong. Does anybody have some idea?

Comment: Code works for me. Try clearing your working directory and re-installing lme4

Comment: It's still not working. I even tested on different computers. it showed same error message. ........

Comment: Works for me as well, using R version 2.15.2.

Comment: See previous comment: there's a SO question with almost exactly the same title, so maybe you need to hunt around a little harder ...

Comment: No, the questions are different, though the titles look like. I do not have a dataset or variable named to "new". I ran the demo codes from glmer().

Comment: Are you absolutely sure?  What are the results of `sessionInfo()`?  Have you tried `rm("new")`? This example is obviously not generally reproducible, or lots of people would have noticed ... Since the error message is identical I would be pretty surprised if it were really a different problem.

Comment: In the `sessionInfo()` you sent offline, you have a very large number of additional packages loaded.  If you start a clean R session and load *only* `lme4` can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: PS running R in 'vanilla' mode is helpful for making sure that you are not loading previous workspaces etc.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and will post the updates. I appreciate your help and efforts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Posted as answer for clarity.)

I can't reproduce this so far: I've tried to replicate your loaded-package environment as far as I can.

```
pkgs <- c("lme4","Matrix","psych","plyr","car",
      "rms","SparseM","Hmisc","Formula","survival",
      "pscl","vcd","gam","coda","lattice",
      "mvtnorm","MASS","gdata","mice","Rcpp",
      "ggplot2","vimcom","setwidth")
sapply(pkgs,library,character.only=TRUE)
sessionInfo()
## attached base packages:
## [1] splines   grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
## [8] methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
##  [1] setwidth_1.0-3   vimcom_0.9-93    ggplot2_0.9.3.1  mice_2.21       
##  [5] Rcpp_0.11.0      gdata_2.13.2     pscl_1.04.4      vcd_1.3-1       
##  [9] gam_1.09.1       coda_0.16-1      mvtnorm_0.9-9997 MASS_7.3-30     
## [13] rms_4.1-3        SparseM_1.03     Hmisc_3.14-3     Formula_1.1-1   
## [17] survival_2.37-7  car_2.0-19       plyr_1.8.1       psych_1.4.2.3   
## [21] lme4_1.0-6       Matrix_1.1-2-2   lattice_0.20-27 
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] cluster_1.14.4      colorspace_1.2-4    dichromat_2.0-0    
##  [4] digest_0.6.4        gtable_0.1.2        gtools_3.3.1       
##  [7] labeling_0.2        latticeExtra_0.6-26 minqa_1.2.3        
## [10] munsell_0.4.2       nlme_3.1-113        nnet_7.3-7         
## [13] proto_0.3-10        randomForest_4.6-7  RColorBrewer_1.0-5 
## [16] reshape2_1.2.2      rpart_4.1-6         scales_0.2.3       
## [19] stringr_0.6.2       tools_3.1.0        

gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
          data = cbpp, family = binomial)
```

(Works.)
I can make this break if I define a variable called `new`:

```
new <- 123
gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
          data = cbpp, family = binomial)

## Error in do.call(new, c(list(Class = "glmResp", family = family), ll[setdiff(names(ll),  : 
##  'what' must be a character string or a function
```

(I thought this bug was fixed *in* v. 1.0-6, but I guess it was fixed subsequently ...)

If I define a *function* called `new` it breaks slightly differently.
If I remove `new` it works again (as previously described).

Can you please try (1) `rm("new")` and (2) starting from a clean session?

Unless someone else (preferably me) can reproduce the error, it's going to be really hard to fix ...

Comment: I have tried glmer(), lmer() on Mac, Windows, unix under R version 3.00-3.03, all of them have produced same error message as I posted here. But when I used a R version back to 2.15.3, the functions work well! However, this also cost me lost many functions from other packages relying on high R version.

Comment: The error message still there with R venilla and a clean session:`> (gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
+               data = cbpp, family = binomial))
Error in do.call(new, c(list(Class = "glmResp", family = family), ll[setdiff(names(ll),  : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base lme4_1.0-6      Matrix_1.1-2-2  lattice_0.20-27 vimcom_0.9-93   setwidth_1.0-3`

Comment: Strange.  Why are `vimcom` and `setwidth` in your "clean" session?

Comment: That's for vim editor. Some good news that I can run glmer now under R 3.03 by leading with `rm("new")` whatever there is "new" or not. Thanks for your great help!

Comment: OK, then **something** in your setup must be creating an object called `new`.  Do you have a `.Rprofile` file defined?  Did you really run `R --vanilla`?  What do you get for `ls()` *immediately* after you start R with `R --vanilla`?

Comment: You're right Ben. I cleaned the .RData and the functions work well. Thank you, Ben!

Comment: Hi Ben. Even the `ls()` shows `character(0)`, I don't know why I still need `rm("new")` to function well `glmer`.

Comment: Neither do I.  What does `getAnywhere("new")` show you?  Have you tried updating to `lme4` version 1.1-5, now on CRAN?

Comment: The `getAnywhere("new")` shows `package:methods` and  After I upgraded the `lme4` the latest version, it works smoothly now. Thanks Ben!